# How To Track EF Queries Back To Source Code

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I saw questions similar to this from over 3 years ago and I am hoping by now, and with EF Core, it can be solved.

I get reports from our DB team about queries that are running slow in production, but with a system the size of ours, it is sometimes hard to track the query back to the code that caused it. Is there some way to pass something along that would allow us to associate an EF generated query back to the code that created it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a new feature in EF Core 2.2 called Query Tags:

example:

```
  var nearestFriends =
      (from f in context.Friends.TagWith(@"This is my spatial query!")
      orderby f.Location.Distance(myLocation) descending
      select f).Take(5).ToList();
```

This will generate the following SQL output:

```
-- This is my spatial query!

SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [f].[Name], [f].[Location]
FROM [Friends] AS [f]
ORDER BY [f].[Location].STDistance(@__myLocation_0) DESC
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/10/17/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2-preview-3/

Comment: Will those comments turn up in SQL Profiler too, for instance?

Comment: If you capture the batch/rpc they will be visible there, and they will be visible in the query plan cache through sys.dm_exec_sql_text.

Comment: Also you can use sp_trace_generateevent if your intention is to simply inject events you can capture with Trace,Profiler or XEvents.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-generateevent-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017